# Journey Builder Custom Event Activation Error

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria, appcenter

I have create a Trigger in my App Center app.  This trigger is able to be dragged onto a Journey as an Entry Event.

The trigger is properly calling my endpoints to get its configure.json (which provides its icons, etc.) and index.html, as documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/example-contact-decision-event.htm .

The Javascript for my index on the Config step on the Event configuration in the Journey is firing the necessary Postmonger events to configure the step, as documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/using-postmonger.htm

I am able to save the Journey, but I AM NOT able to Activate the Journey.  I receive an Error with no other description or details.  I have verified in Google dev tools Network Sources that the Error array is indeed empty so there is no getting any details there.  I have been able to Activate the Journey using a different Entry source, so I am near certain there is some configuration issue missing, but the question is what?

Any further troubleshooting assistance or similar is greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Mike Lipski

Comment: Can you share the external link to your config.json file?

Comment: My site is not yet deployed, Eliot.  I am running on locahost using a secure tunnel (ngrok) to redirect to my localhost so I cannot guarantee my solution will be running at all time for you to ping it.  I can provide the JSON which is as follows:

Comment: '{"workflowApiVersion":"1.1","metaData":{"icon":"img/ApplicationImage.jpg","iconSmall":"img/ServiceImage.jpg"},"type":"EVENT","lang":{"en-US":{"name":"Watch me go!","description":"Mike"}},"configurationArguments":{"applicationExtensionKey":"efg903","save":{"url":"https://requestb.in/1alekg21","verb":"POST","body":"","format":"json","useJwt":false},"publish":{"url":"https://requestb.in/1alekg21","verb":"POST","body":"","format":"json","useJwt":false}},"userInterfaces":{"configModal":{"url":"index.html"},"summary":[]}}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issue specifying a Data Extension for use, despite The documentation specifically states to specify a data extension OR a schema.  Specifying a Data Extension does not activate. When specifying a Schema (in a Postmonger callback), the Journey activates AND creates a new Data Extension based upon that schema.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the config.json example you supplied in your comment, there are a couple of issues here:

1. No `icon‌​Small` is required in config.json
2. You don't need to define a `save` object in config.json

   Understand that while config.json is similar between Activities and Events, the interaction behavior is different. You will need to call `updateEvent` [using Postmonger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/using-postmonger.htm) to pass a `schema` or `dataExtensionId` to Journey Builder. You can also optionally set a default value for this in config.json as [explained here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-events.htm).

   I'd recommend you refer to the example config.json, index.html and customEvent.js code provided [on this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/example-contact-decision-event.htm) as a framework when developing your Custom Event.

Comment: I copied the wrong json, Eliot.  I have set a dataExtensionId and did call updateEvent using Postmonger.  Not doing so actually results in the Event being null when returning to a Saved, unpublished (because it cannot be activated) Journey.  (Repro steps -> Create Journey w/ incorrect json and missing events->Save Journey->Return to Journey->Note that the Entry source is an Event, but it is now a null event).  When these issues you have mentioned are corrected, Activation still fails with Error having no other information.  I have referred extensively to the docs you have recommended.

Comment: Can you provide a gist or link to your config.json file and I will build a Custom Event and try to reproduce the behaviour you are experiencing?

Comment: Eliot, thanks so much for the offer of help.  I will have to set something back up as I have moved onto to a different solution to manage the behavior I desire; however, I would much prefer to go this original route that I had intended.  As it is late in the day on Friday and this weekend my time to be in front of the computer will be limited, I will set something back up that you may ping on Monday if you're still willing.  I will replay here on Monday.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi Elliot,  my config.json event can be hit here: https://pfllink-mtl.ngrok.io/journeybuilder/config.json

It is very basic at this point and I was setting the Data Extension in the Postmonger event.  I will elave this running all night.  Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Thanks, I've copied your config.json file and will work on building a custom event in the next 24-48 hours

Comment: FYI, Eliot, I was able to Activate a Journey with this Custom Event.  It seems there is an issue specifying a Data Extension for use.  The documentation specifically states to specify a data extension OR a schema; however, specifying a Data Extension does not activate.  When specifying a Schema (in my Postmonger callback), the Journey activates AND creates a new Data Extension based upon that schema.  I am going through some testing now to see if there is other things I can specify in that schema as the documentation is lacking for that object.

Comment: That's good to know! Please let me know how you get on.